# awk single column to multiple columns

Tags: awk, grep, multiple-columns

My input file looks like this,

```
0   1.0069770730517629     
0   1.0068122761874614     
0   1.0004297763706849     
1   1.0069220626905635     
1   1.0079998216945956     
1   1.0006092898635817     
2   1.0071274842017928    
2   1.0083750686808803     
2   1.0006868227863552     
3   1.0073693844413083     
3   1.0086546525825624     
3   1.0007234442925264
```

And I want the output file looks like this,

```
0   1.0069770730517629     1.0068122761874614     1.0004297763706849     
1   1.0069220626905635     1.0079998216945956     1.0006092898635817     
2   1.0071274842017928     1.0083750686808803     1.0006868227863552     
3   1.0073693844413083     1.0086546525825624     1.0007234442925264
```

I want to use grep or awk to split the single column to multiple ones. 
Can anyone help me, pls?

Comment: Do you want to combine every 3 lines into one line or every line that starts with the same number into one line?

Comment: I wanna combine every 3 lines that start with the same number into one line.

Comment: and what if 4 lines start with the same number? Would you combine the first 3, leave the 4th as-is, and then start on the next batch or do something else? btw grep is a tool for searching for a regexp in a file and printing the matching line (`g/re/p` get it?). It has absolutely nothing to do with what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do not know how this awk code is working, but I can use [Google](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/208027-merge-multiple-lines-same-file-common-key-using-awk.html) :) Try this: `awk 's != $1 || NR ==1{s=$1;if(p){print p};p=$0;next}
{sub($1,"",$0);p=p""$0;}END{print p}' file | column -t` I'm sure someone can optimize the awk code to get rid of  `column -t`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically state "combine 3 lines":

```
paste - - - < file | awk -v OFS="    " '{print $1, $2, $4, $6}'
```

I'm going to assume that the file is already sorted.

Another take: just awk, and no assumption about sorted-ness

```
gawk -v OFS="    " '
    {values[$1] = values[$1] OFS $2} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (key in values) print key values[key]
    }
' file
```

Comment: `paste`, nice idea! Another possibility: `printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" $(< file)`

Comment: @Cyrus Or `printf "%s %s%.0s %s%.0s %s\n" $(< file.csv)`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Perfect! Bash only. Post as answer.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, insane!

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not make any assumptions about the number of values to print, nor it assumes the file is ordered.

```
#!/bin/bash

sort -n "file.csv" > "file.csv.tmp"

awk -v lastline="false" '{
    if (lastline != $1)
    {
        if (NR>1) { printf "\n"};
        {printf "%s   %s", $1, $2; lastline=$1; next};
    }
    else { printf "   %s", $2};

} END { printf "\n"}' "file.csv.tmp" #>"file.csv"
```

This program sorts the file first to ensure all values of `$1` are together.

Then the value of `lastline` is used to control the actions.
The var `lastline` is initially set to `false` to ensure it matches no `$1` value.
If `lastline` is not a repeat (does not match `$1`) the values of `$1` and `$2` get printed. ... And `lastline` is updated to this `$1` value.
If `lastline` is a repeat (equal to `$1`) only `$2` gets printed.
To make the format correct, there is a newline printed for each "new" `$1` row. ... And at the end.

If replacing the original "file.csv" is needed, remove the comment character (#) to allow the redirection in the last line.

Changed the loop to a if...else.
Maybe is more readable like this.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `pr` with the same awk ending

```
pr -3at file | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$4,$6}'
```

used tab delimiter instead of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This works (in bash and zsh):

```
printf "%s %s%.s %s%.s %s\n" $(< file)
```

Or more portable, as printf and cat are available almost everywhere. (I do not think that this qualifies to the [useless "use of cat" award](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html), or so I hope :)

```
printf "%s %s%.s %s%.s %s\n" $(cat  file)
```

Only iff:

- the file is ordered, with all first column values together, and
- there are exactly 3 values to print.

Needs [a trick](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) of printf to [avoid printing some fields](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/), or with more precise wording: "print 0 characters from an string": "%.s".

Original idea from Cyrus as: `printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" $(< file)`